# Is there something wrong about my proof about right inverses?

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

I was working on the statement: Prove that there exists function $g: Y \rightarrow X$ such that $f \circ g = I_y$ if and only if $f$ is a surjection.

Here is my question: working on the forwards implication "There exists function $g: Y\rightarrow X$ such that $f \circ g= I_y \implies f $ is a surjection", I came to the reasoning that since the identity map $I_y$ is a bijection, we can say that it then follows that the functions composing this bijective function are both a bijection. Hence, $f$ and $g$ are both bijective, which then shows that $f$ is a surjection as well (by definition of bijection).

Is there something wrong with my line of reasoning? Something feels fishy here and I can't seem to put my finger on it.

Comment: It feels “fishy” because you doesn’t prove that if  $f \circ g$ is a bijection, then $f$ and $g$ are bijections. Can you prove that? (*Spoiler alert*: You can’t, since its false.)

Comment: I see. I guess I was using the theorem that I intended to use backwards.